# How would something faster than light be affected by a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, faster-than-light

What would happen if something (having mass) existed which has a greater speed than that of light?

How would it be affected by the black hole when it, say, speeds past a black hole? Would it experience any pull? Would it be destroyed? Or something amazing would happen?

Comment: Which non-canon meaning of "faster than light" do you intend to use?  By canon physics, nothing can travel faster than the speed of light, so you are describing something that simply doesn't exist.  There are many non-cannot physics models which do have FTL, but they don't all agree, and certainly don't agree when you put it in the most challenging gravitic environments possible near a black hole.

Comment: As a side comment, it's difficult to give an answer grounded in physics to a question that violates those laws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably exactly what you would expect would happen: it would experience the gravitational pull exactly the same as any other object would.  But with the higher velocity, it would experience less (total) pull due to the shorter duration before being out of range again.

(Note: light experiences a gravitational pull despite being massless).

Comment: So would it go past it without being changed (*in any manner*)?

Comment: No, it's trajectory would simply *curve less* than an object moving more slowly.

Comment: Okay, I understand now... Thanks :)

Comment: I believe that it would be influenced by the black hole slightly differently from a subluminal object (at least when considered from a reference frame in which the black hole is not stationary), as the effects of gravity propagate at light speed (iirc). I don't have time to work out the light cones for this scenario, however.

Comment: Gravity does propagate at the speed of light, but it is also a *field* so there's already gravity there when the superluminal object passes through the area.  The superluminal object's *gravitational effect on the black hole* would lag behind.